# org.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER in Tomcat9

Tags: tomcat9

I'm upgrading from Tomcat8 to Tomcat9 and sendError does not pass the custom error message that I want to share with the consumer.

I read that sendError and org.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER property is deprecated since Tomcat 8.5 but it seems like it works in Tomcat9 for some people.

Once this said then my main question is ... what is then the best way for a permanent solution on sending error messages when responding with error status code? 
If the answer is that sendError is still compatible with Tomcat9 then my question is where this org.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER should be configured? in which file? and in case it does not exists which is the code I need to add to the file to make it work? Because I found no entry in any of the files in my config directory for this property.

Thanks in advance
PS: I know that there are many posts for this topic but I'm afraid they are some old and/or some are based in Spring and this is not my case.

Answer (score -1):

Amusingly sad question. As far as I can see, Tomcat developers feel that:

1. "because HTTP/2 doesn't support Reason",
2. "Reason is optional in HTTP/1.x and primarily intended for human use", and
3. "smart developer knows HTTP status codes already & doesn't need explanatory text"

They can just delete support for it.

From my perspective of protocol compatibility & systems integration, I think this is just astoundingly wrong. My perspective would be, that so long as HTTP/1.x is supported, all features of HTTP/1.x (whether a client "should rely" on these or not) should be supported.

My belief would be that it should be the overall system owner/ architect's decision -- encompassing the client & server applications, as well as Tomcat -- who makes the decision that they do or don't need Reason Codes.

Tomcat developers are not responsible for these overall systems and, from my perspective, should not be making decisions to delete commonly-expected features of protocols they claim to support which break what they are not responsible for.

However, that seems to be their decision.

- http://literatejava.com/web/http-status-reason-broken-in-tomcat-9/

Comment: Totally agree with you. There are many old systems where this kind of decisions means a big effort or directly decide that their system is not compatible with those recent Tomcat releases ... what is not a good thing after all.